# HTML5 Three Column layout with resizable left/center and fixed right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a (full screen) three column layout with a resizable left/center column. The right column should always be fixed size and always to the right.

I'm using the resize style to allow changing the size of the left area. The center area doesn't adjust in size but just follows along and creates a gap to the right hand DIV. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've been trying with DIVs. I'll be happy to use flex if that's a better way. Only needs to run on HTML5 since it will require web-sockets. Would like to avoid JavaScript if it can simply be styled.

Thanks :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="connect-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
        <style>
            body    {
                    margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                    }

            #container      {
                                overflow: none;
                                height: 100vh;
                                width: 100vw;
                                margin: 0;
                                padding: 0;
                            }

            #a_left         {
                                float:left;
                                height: 100vh;
                                width: 75%;
                                background-color: black;
                                overflow:auto;
                                resize: horizontal;
                            }
            #a_center       {
                                float:left;
                                height: 100vh;
                                min-width: 80px;
                                width:10%;
                                overflow: none;
                                background-color:darkgray;
                            }
            #a_right        {
                                float:right;
                                height: 100vh;
                                width: 40px;
                                min-width: 40px;
                                max-width: 40px;
                                overflow:none;
                                background-color:darkslategray;
                                color:white;
                            }

            #al_text        {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 95%;
                                overflow-y: auto;
                                background-color: black;
                                color:white;
                            }
            #al_cmd         {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 5%;
                                overflow: none;
                                background-color: darkslategray;
                            }
            #ac_map         {   width:100%;
                                height: 25%;
                                overflow: hidden;
                                background-color: #222222;
                                color: white;
                            }
            #ac_paged       {   width:100%;
                                height: 75%;
                                overflow-y: auto;
                                background-color: #222222;
                                color: white;
                            }


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div id="a_left">
            <div id="al_text" role="log" aria-live="polite">
                A lot of text goes here.
            </div>
            <div id="al_cmd">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%; color:white;">Command</td>
                        <td style="width:70%;"><input style="width:97%;" type="text" id="message"/></td>
                        <td style="width:15%;"><input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send" disabled="disabled" onclick="onSendClick()"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                            
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /a_left -->
        <div id="a_center">
            <div id="ac_map">
                An image goes here.
            </div>
            <div id="ac_paged" aria-live="polite">
                Text that sticks goes here and it could be very long. 
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /a_right -->
        <div id="a_right">
            In<br/>
            Eq<br/>
            He<br/>
        </div>        
        </div> <!-- /container -->

        </body>
</html>
```

EDIT1:

After posting this question and implementing the solution from Antonio, I realized that I would get a better result if I first implemented a large left column DIV and the fixed right column DIV. Then inside the left column DIV I place the left and center and make them resizable.

It creates a better overall UX when dragging the resizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using display flex.
You can put the initial width: "width: 75%"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="connect-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
        <style>

body    {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          }

  #container      {
                      /*! overflow: none; */
                      height: 100vh;
                      width: 100vw;
                      margin: 0;
                      padding: 0;
                      display: flex;
                  }

  #a_left         {
                      /*! float:left; */
                      height: 100vh;
                      width: 75%; /* <--- Initial Width */
                      background-color: black;
                      overflow:auto;
                      resize: horizontal;
                  }
  #a_center       {
                      /*! float:left; */
                      height: 100vh;
                      min-width: 80px;
                      /*! width:10%; */
                      /*! overflow: none; */
                      background-color:darkgray;
                      flex: auto;
                  }
  #a_right        {
                      /*! float:right; */
                      height: 100vh;
                      width: 40px;
                      /*! min-width: 40px; */
                      /*! max-width: 40px; */
                      overflow:none;
                      background-color:darkslategray;
                      color:white;
                  }

  #al_text        {
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 95%;
                      overflow-y: auto;
                      background-color: black;
                      color:white;
                  }
  #al_cmd         {
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 5%;
                      overflow: none;
                      background-color: darkslategray;
                  }
  #ac_map         {   width:100%;
                      height: 25%;
                      overflow: hidden;
                      background-color: #222222;
                      color: white;
                  }
  #ac_paged       {   width:100%;
                      height: 75%;
                      overflow-y: auto;
                      background-color: #222222;
                      color: white;
                  }



    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="a_left">
            <div id="al_text" role="log" aria-live="polite">
                A lot of text goes here.
            </div>
            <div id="al_cmd">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%; color:white;">Command</td>
                        <td style="width:70%;"><input style="width:97%;" type="text" id="message"/></td>
                        <td style="width:15%;"><input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send" disabled="disabled" onclick="onSendClick()"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /a_left -->
        <div id="a_center">
            <div id="ac_map">
                An image goes here.
            </div>
            <div id="ac_paged" aria-live="polite">
                Text that sticks goes here and it could be very long.
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /a_right -->
        <div id="a_right">
            In<br/>
            Eq<br/>
            He<br/>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works fantastically well! :-) I would never have figured that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="connect-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
      <style>
         body    {
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         }
         #al_text        {
         width: 100%;
         height: 95%;
         overflow-y: auto;
         background-color: black;
         color:white;
         }
         #al_cmd         {
         width: 100%;
         height: 5%;
         overflow: none;
         background-color: darkslategray;
         }
         #ac_map         {   width:100%;
         height: 25%;
         overflow: hidden;
         background-color: #222222;
         color: white;
         }
         #ac_paged       {   width:100%;
         height: 75%;
         overflow-y: auto;
         background-color: #222222;
         color: white;
         }
         .container {
         display: flex;
         flex-flow: row nowrap;
         width: 100%;
         div{
         height: 100vh;
         }
         }
         #a_left {
         overflow: auto;
         resize: horizontal;
         height: 100vh;
         max-width: 75%;
         width: 100%;
         }
         #a_center {
         min-width: 80px;
         width: 100%;
         overflow: none;
         }
         #a_right {
         max-width: 40px;
         width: 100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div id="a_left">
            <div id="al_text" role="log" aria-live="polite">
               A lot of text goes here.
            </div>
            <div id="al_cmd">
               <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="width:10%; color:white;">Command</td>
                     <td style="width:70%;"><input style="width:97%;" type="text" id="message"/></td>
                     <td style="width:15%;"><input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send" disabled="disabled" onclick="onSendClick()"></td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /a_left -->
         <div id="a_center">
            <div id="ac_map">
               An image goes here.
            </div>
            <div id="ac_paged" aria-live="polite">
               Text that sticks goes here and it could be very long. 
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /a_right -->
         <div id="a_right">
            In<br/>
            Eq<br/>
            He<br/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /container -->
   </body>
</html>
```

The `#a_left` is set to a max-width of `75%` and the `#a_center` should occupy at least `80px` leaving the `#a_right` to occupy a max width of `40px`

Comment: There's an issue with this, it doesn't work quite as well as the flex solution proposed by Antonio. It seems to "bounce" the center section back when I drag too far. Thanks though, it was definitely better than what I had!